# Silence the output of db.update in web.py

Tags: python, database, web.py

I'm using web.py to abstract work with a database.  I loop over a series of webpages to scrape and collect relevant info into the variable compiled_essay.  I then update a column in a database to hold the essay.

```
for update_number in range(len(user_list)):    
    db.update('users',where="username = '%(user)s'"%{"user":username},essay_data=compiled_essay)
```

The problem is this ends up printing out the db command in the python shell I'm using:

```
0.0 (update_number): UPDATE users SET essay_data = 'lots_of_text' WHERE username = 'the_user'
```

My question is how can I silence the db.update command so it doesn't print large amounts of text for every update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printing is enabled only in the development mode.

You can explicitly disable it by adding the following line before creating the db.

```
web.config.debug = False
```

or, by setting:

```
db.printing = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this in the Python shell, one way would be setting the output to a variable:

```
for update_number in range(len(user_list)):    
    x = db.update('users',where="username = '%(user)s'"%{"user":username},essay_data=compiled_essay)
```

Comment: No dice, I get mostly the same output.  x ends up holding an int.  I believe it's a success code.

Comment: Then the module you are using must be printing this output by itself, can you perhaps give this module an argument like debug=False?

Comment: The flag was _test=True.  Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion in the comments, the flag `_test=True` silences the output.

```
db.update('users',where="username = '%(user)s'"%{"user":username},essay_data=compiled_essay,_test=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

web.config.debug = False still did not helped. Some outupt still was done.

Comment out line in file:
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\web\httpserver.py

line:

```
print >> outfile, utils.safestr(msg) ->
#print >> outfile, utils.safestr(msg)
```